# sqlloader loading unix timestamp

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I cannot seem to load a unix timestamp using SQLLDR.

```
load data infile 'AST_BusinessService_export.csv' 
append into table ccp.services_temp 
 fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS    
 (NAME, SHORT_DESCRIPTION, CREATE_DATE EXPRESSION "(cast(:CREATE_DATE)as date) - TO_DATE('01/01/1970 00:00:00', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')) *
24 * 60 * 60")
```

I am trying to pass

```
TEST-CI-GO,TIER2_H1_2 FW,1233817523
```

Error I receive is `SQL*Loader-291: Invalid bind variable CREATE_DATE in SQL string for column CREATE_DATE.`

**UPDATE**

```
load data infile 'AST_BusinessService_export.csv'
append into table ccp.services_temp
 fields terminated by ',' optionally enclosed by '"' TRAILING NULLCOLS
 (NAME, SHORT_DESCRIPTION, CREATE_DATE EXPRESSION to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * CREATE_DATE
```

error is `Expecting SQL string, found "to_date".
 (NAME, SHORT_DESCRIPTION, CREATE_DATE EXPRESSION to_date('19700101',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your input looks like:

```
TEST-CI-GO,TIER2_H1_2 FW,1233817523
```

I believe you want to convert to date by doing something like:

```
select to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * 1233817523
from dual;
```

Output:

```
2/5/2009 7:05:23 AM
```

So start at the epoch and add that many seconds (converted to days since thats what Oracle wants for adding to dates)

EDIT:

For a table like this:

```
create table test_unixdate
(
id number,
secs_since_epoch number,
converted_date date
);
```

And data like this:

```
1,1233817521
2,1243817522
3,1253817523
4,
5,1263817525
```

Your sqlldr might look like:

```
LOAD DATA
infile 'test_unixdate.csv'
badfile 'test_unixdate.bad'
discardfile 'test_unixdate.dis'
APPEND
INTO TABLE test_unixdate
Fields terminated by ","
Optionally enclosed by '"'
trailing nullcols
(
id nullif id=blanks,
secs_since_epoch nullif secs_since_epoch=blanks,
converted_date "to_date('19700101', 'YYYYMMDD') + ( 1 / 24 / 60 / 60 ) * :secs_since_epoch"
)
```

Output (select * from test_unixdate):

```
1   1233817521  2/5/2009 7:05:21 AM
2   1243817522  6/1/2009 12:52:02 AM
3   1253817523  9/24/2009 6:38:43 PM
4       
5   1263817525  1/18/2010 12:25:25 PM
```

Comment: Note, the result of this function returns time in UTC. Consider to convert it to local times.

Comment: im not sure how to write this in ctl file?